# How to debug | Some times the "Save Draft" button seems to spin but does not actually save

Tags: save-post, draft

I am using wordpress 3.5.1 and lately there seems to be a recurring problem with the save draft function where it seems like the draft was saved (i.e the wheel finishes spinning without an error message) but alas, all edits are lost. This happens both in the regular editor as well as in the distraction free wring space (where it is extremely frustrating, as all edits are lost when returning to the regular editing mode). 
I couldn't find a discussion about this problem in the other forums or any instructions on how to debug this or find the source of the problem. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to Twenty Twelve. Does it still happen?

Comment: Could it be a PHP memory issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress root directory,open file wp-config.php,and find this code:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

and just set the value to false somehow like this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

so that all errors will display,hope this can be helpful to u!

and also the best way is to resintall wordpress if it's convient to u